# scalaのobjectを事前初期化する方法

Tags: scala

```
trait A

object B extends A {
  println("B")
}

object C exetends A {
  println("C")
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("RUN")
  }
}
```

このとき、標準出力には

`RUN`

しか表示されません。

これをどうにか、明示的なアクセスなく

```
B
C
RUN
```

と表示されるようにしたいです。なんらかのかたちでアクセスされる前に初期化したいです。
特定のアノテーションをつけると、そのクラス・オブジェクトにアクセスして初期化してくれるとか、型パラメータAを指定したとき、そのサブクラスにアクセスできる、みたいな方法はないですか？

Answer (score 1):

アノテーションなんかないけど、それを使ったら、ちゃんと

```
 B C RUN
```

を表示されると思います:

```
 trait A

 object B extends A {
   {
     println("B")
   }
 }

 object C extends A {
   println("C")
 }

 object Main {
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     B
     C
     println("RUN")
   }
 }
```

Scalaのオブジェクトはlazyですから、他の方法はないと思います。

その返事は不満足場合は、すみません。日本人じゃないですから、質問を勘違いしたかもしれないです。